# Autocomplete Text box Simple way

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Airline search
[image: Airline search]

I am creating a web page that allows searching the flight availability,
for that, I want to design autocomplete text box for FROM and TO destinations and the first option from the search autocomplete has to select by default.
I used html5 datalist property, unfortunately, it's giving only limited css properties. I searched a lot for the same but all are very complex methods. Anyone can help by giving some simple methods or proper links that help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectize.js to create an autocomplete. It's really simple to use, just create an HTML select with options and give it an id and pass this id in selectize.

for example:

```
<select id="fromInput">
  <option value="nyk">New york</option>
  <option value="sf">San Francisco</option>
</select>
```

js

```
   var select = $('#fromInput').selectize({
        create: true,
        sortField: 'text'
    });

  //setting default value
  $select[0].selectize.setValue("nyk");
```

for more details: https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/